# Display column names based on 0, 1 in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to make the following transformation in python

from

```
   A  B  C  D  E  
   x  1  0  0  0 
   y  0  1  1  0 
   z  1  0  0  1
```

to

```
   x  B 
   y  C,D
   z  A,E
```

Do you  have any  ideas ?

Comment: How are you currently storing your labels and 1s and 0s?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `dot`

```
df=df.set_index('A')
df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
A
x      B
y    C,D
z    B,E
dtype: object
```